# Is it possible to show a gauge chart passing an URL to a service like Google Chart?

Tags: asp.net, charts

I would like to show a simple gauge to my asp.net application. What are the options ? 
Is it possible to simply pass an url to google chart service that 'return' the gauge 'image' ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net has a built-in charting control from .net 4 onwards, and its a free download for .net 3.5. See [Built-in Charting Controls (VS 2010 and .NET 4 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx) for more details and a lot of links with examples.